# What tools do I need to make realtime ocr app with python?

Tags: python, ocr, real-time

I am looking for some information about performing OCR in realtime, using e.g. laptop built-in webcam, with python. 
Can you please tell me how to start? Which libraries are best for that? 
Is it possible to make app to recognize some text from small document without scanning or making photo using only python?